# AngularJs show first and last from filtered list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, angular-ng-if

Have some problem show only first and last repeated element after filtering empty string from array.

My code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.items = [
        { name: "item1", color: "green", form: "" },
        { name: "item2", color: "", form: "circle" },
        { name: "item3", color: "red", form: "" },
        { name: "item4", color: "", form: "oval" },
        { name: "item5", color: "blue", form: "" },
        { name: "item6", color: "", form: "square" },
        { name: "item7", color: "yellow", form: "" },
        { name: "item8", color: "", form: "rectangle" }     
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.form == ''">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.color}}
</div>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.color == ''">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.form}}
</div>
<br />
</body>
```

But I need show only first and last elenemt in list. 
Ex. in first list: item1-green and item7-yellow (item3-red and item5-blue must be hidden), second list item2-circle and item8-rectangle.

Comment: if one group is only colors and the other group is only forms (shapes), why do you have them combined into a single list?  also, `ng-if` **is not** a filter.

Comment: Please show expected results. Not clear what objective is

Comment: Objective is show only first and last element from every list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created custom filter for your use case. 
Basically the filter will return array by filtering the empty value for the passed parameter(form and color).

After filtering, you can use `$first` and `$last` with `ng-if` to display only first and last elements.

see the code below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  

  myApp.filter('customFilter', function() {
      return function(input, param) {
        if(input.length == 0) { return [];}
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
          if(item[param] && item[param]!= '') {
            result.push(item);
          }
        });
        return result;
     }
  })

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.items = [
        { name: "item1", color: "green", form: "" },
        { name: "item2", color: "", form: "circle" },
        { name: "item3", color: "red", form: "" },
        { name: "item4", color: "", form: "oval" },
        { name: "item5", color: "blue", form: "" },
        { name: "item6", color: "", form: "square" },
        { name: "item7", color: "yellow", form: "" },
        { name: "item8", color: "", form: "rectangle" }     
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<div ng-repeat="item in items | customFilter:'color'" ng-if="$first || $last">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.color}}
</div>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | customFilter:'form'" ng-if="$first || $last">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.form}}
</div>
<br />
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only wanted to show first and last element of items inside `ng-repeat` you could use `$first` & `$last` variable of `ng-repeat` template which indicated `$first` & `$last` occurrence if they are true.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$first || $last">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.form}}
</div>
```

**Update**

For such situation you should prefer to do custom filter, which will accept `array`, `propertyName` & `valueToCheck`. At the end it will return 1st and last element

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| returnFirstAndLastValue: 'form': ''">
   {{item.name}}-{{item.color}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items| returnFirstAndLastValue: 'color': ''">
   {{item.name}}-{{item.form}}
</div>
```

**Filter**

```
myApp.filter('returnFirstAndLastValue', function(){
  return function(array, prop, valueToCheck){
    var length = (array || []).length, tempOutput = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(ele, index){
      if(ele[prop] === valueToCheck)
        tempOutput.push(ele);
    })
    return tempOutput.filter(function(element, index){
      if(index == 0 || index == (tempOutput.length - 1) )
        return element;
    })
  }
})
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/X44PpOv7Fy5JKAv118or?p=preview)

Comment: This example show first and last element from default array, but I need from filtered array :(

Comment: @KingStakh sorry for late response..I've created the filter which will get rid of `$first` & `$last` checking on the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: thank you for response it's one more example solved problem!

Comment: @KingStakh really Glad to know that..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it ;)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.items = [
        { name: "item1", color: "green", shape: "" },
        { name: "item2", color: "", shape: "circle" },
        { name: "item3", color: "red", shape: "" },
        { name: "item4", color: "", shape: "oval" },
        { name: "item5", color: "blue", shape: "" },
        { name: "item6", color: "", shape: "square" },
        { name: "item7", color: "yellow", form: "" },
        { name: "item8", color: "", shape: "rectangle" }     
    ];
  
 $scope.shape = function(item){
  return !(item.color == '')
 };
 
 $scope.color = function(item){
  return !(item.shape == '')
 };  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:shape" ng-if="$first || $last">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.color}}
</div>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:color" ng-if="$first || $last">
    {{item.name}}-{{item.shape}}
</div>
<br />
</body>
```